# unable to get value of `div` elements

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I need to build a calculator with vanilla JS.

But I'm having problems when I try to get the values of the `div` elements. Can anyone help me with it?

```
    <div id="num_keyboard">
        <div class="btn-opt" value="1">1</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="2">2</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="3">3</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="4">4</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="5">5</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="6">6</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="7">7</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="8">8</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="9">9</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" value="0">0</div>
  </div>

<script>
    const num_keyboard = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-opt");
    let numArray = Array.from(num_keyboard);

    console.log(numArray);

    for(let c = 0; c <= numArray.length; c++) {
      numArray[c].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(`Foi: ${numArray[c].value}`);
      })
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements do not have values.

Comment: Change `numArray[c].value` to `numArray[c].getAttribute("data-value")` and in the div add `data-` before value because divs don't get values.

Comment: As imvain2 mentioned, use data attributes. Also, use event target in the event callback :
numArray[c].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        alert(`Foi: ${event.target.getAttribute("data-value")}`);
})

Comment: Use buttons....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `value` of the buttons with `.value`. You need to use `.attributes["value"]`

That returns an HTML attribute, however, so you'll need to get the textContent. For example, `numArray[c].attributes["value"].textContent`

This returns the number as a string. From there you can turn it into an int.

EDIT:
Looking at the code, and at your profile, I can tell this is some of your first javascript, so I wanted to provide a fuller answer of how you can improve this.

First, as others suggested, you should use buttons. This is what's known as [semantic markup](https://html.com/semantic-markup/#:%7E:text=Semantic%20markup%20is%20the%20use,elements%20contained%20in%20the%20document.), which is just a fancy way of saying you use the right elements for the job. You click it to do a thing, so the right element is a button. Semantic markup helps the user, the browser, and any accessibility tools know what's going on.

Next, using custom attributes is supported, but [you need to add a `data-` to the beginning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). This is because HTML is a living specification, and it is getting new attributes. To prevent your code from interfering with any new attributes added, you should add `data-` or, if I remember correctly, basically any attribute name with a `-`.

This point, however, doesn't actually matter when you use an `input` with `type="button"`, as `value` is an established, native attribute. So, instead of the divs and `data-`, try this:

```html
    <div id="num_keyboard">
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="0"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="1"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="2"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="3"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="4"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="5"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="6"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="7"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="8"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn-opt" value="9"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also, to be clear, I agree with other commenters that there are other, superior ways to handle this. This seems super hack-y to me, too. This does answer the question, however

Comment: Well explained. It's nice that you took the time to write that up. It's important that new HTML developers start off on the right foot and realize that there are a ton of different tags that have clear purposes (semantically), and grow up within the technology not "over-div-ifying" everything. Thanks for taking the time to help him out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for help, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

just get the innerHTML or as suggested use textContent

```js
const num_keyboard = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-opt");
    let numArray = Array.from(num_keyboard);

   
    for(let c = 0; c < numArray.length; c++) {
      numArray[c].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(`Foi: ${numArray[c].textContent}`);
      })
    };
```

```html
<div id="num_keyboard">
        <div class="btn-opt" >1</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >2</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >3</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >4</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >5</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >6</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >7</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >8</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >9</div>
        <div class="btn-opt" >0</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Pretty hacky approach - the comments suggesting using data- attributes are more on point with what this user needs.

Comment: The use of "value" in DIV is semantically odd, anyways. IMO the markup should be changed to better express the semantics.

Comment: solution updated to remove value from divs

Comment: The value of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) would be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Imvain's comment and iota's answer re using data- attributes are a good start.

Considering that what you are building is a calculator, it would actually be better (i.e. more semantically correct) to use the BUTTON tag for each of the buttons on the calculator.

Button does support the attribute, "value".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0):

Since `div` elements do not have a value attribute, you could use data-attributes instead.

```js
const num_keyboard = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-opt");
let numArray = Array.from(num_keyboard);

for (let c = 0; c < numArray.length; c++) {
  numArray[c].addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(`Foi: ${numArray[c].dataset.value}`);
  })
};
```

```html
<div id="num_keyboard">
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="1">1</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="2">2</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="3">3</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="4">4</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="5">5</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="6">6</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="7">7</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="8">8</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="9">9</div>
  <div class="btn-opt" data-value="0">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push and pop pressed keys onto a stack (array). This way you can utilize a clear entry function.

**Note:** The value attribute does not exist for a `<div>` element. I would change this to a data attribute i.e. `data-value` and access it via `element.dataset.value`.

```js
const history = [];

const refresh = () => {
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = history.join('');
};

const  handleClearEntry  =    ()   => history.pop();
const handleClearHistory =    ()   => history.splice(0, history.length);
const    handleInput     = (value) => history.push(value);

const handleClick = (e) => {  
  switch (e.target.dataset.value) {
    case 'CE':
      handleClearEntry();
      break;
    case 'C':
      handleClearHistory();
      break;
    default:
      handleInput(e.target.dataset.value);
      break;
  }
  refresh();
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('.btn-opt')].forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  color: #EEE;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.output {
  min-height: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: thin solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.keyboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 0.25em;
  grid-column-gap: 0.25em;
  flex: 1;
}

.btn-opt {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #222;
  background: #333;
  color: #EEE;
}

.btn-opt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="output"></div>
  <div class="keyboard">
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="1">1</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="2">2</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="3">3</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="4">4</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="5">5</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="6">6</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="7">7</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="8">8</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="9">9</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="0">0</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="CE">CE</div>
    <div class="btn-opt" data-value="C">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div>` for `<button>` :

```
    <div id="num_keyboard">
        <button class="btn-opt" value="1">1</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="2">2</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="3">3</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="4">4</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="5">5</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="6">6</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="7">7</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="8">8</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="9">9</button >
        <button class="btn-opt" value="0">0</button >
  </div>

<script>
    const num_keyboard = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-opt");
    let numArray = Array.from(num_keyboard);

    console.log(numArray);

    for(let c = 0; c <= numArray.length; c++) {
      numArray[c].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(`Foi: ${numArray[c].value}`);
      })
    };

  </script>
```